# Austrian vs Yekkish Minhagim

Tags: minhag, yekke

I'm aware that there are some similarities between Austrian minhagim and Yekkish ones. One example would be that in both communities boys begin wearing a tallis at their Bar Mitzvah, rather than waiting until marriage. Nevertheless, I've been assured by Austrian Jews that they are most definitely not Yekkes. What are some minhagim that differ between the two communities?

Comment: Here's a link from the KAYJ forum detailing differences between the Mahari"l (R' Ja'akov haLevi Mölin Vermeiser, Jekkisch) and the Terumas haDeshen (Österreicher) http://www.kayj.net/en/forum/minhogim/71-austrian-minhogim-a-german-minhogim#2089 ed seq. Please note that minhogim do change in 600+ years though, even while some remain consistent.

Comment: I am nowhere near an expert on Western Ashkenazi minhagim, but I thought that Yekkes began wearing a tallis even from before bar mitzvah, and the link that @NoachMiFrankfurt provided seems to confirm that. Maybe Noach can help me out here?

Comment: @ezra, in my family, we appear to follow the Austrian minhog w/ regards to tallis age, but in Breuer's, even most of the ketonim wear talliyos and they require both bochurim and ba'alei bottim to wear a tallis by Shacharis.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Do you think Frankfurt am Main ever belonged to the Kingdom of Austria ever?

Comment: @ezra, no, that has more to do with how many Jekkes have assimilated into the mainstream MO and yeshivish communities. I wrote a dvar Toroh on that for Parashas Shelach

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Yeah, just looked at a map and Frankfurt's not close to Austria. Plus, when it comes to minhagim, I tend to want to lump everyone into one group when it's much more complicated than that. Yekkes can have varying customs too... ;)

Comment: @ezra, that's true. *Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel* makes note of alternate nuschaos.

Comment: How many original Austrians do you know who themselves, parents or grandparents are not either Hungarian or Galician? Re. the talis, IIRC real Austrians and Yekkes (we'll refer to them as Germans) follow the custom of Mahar"sh Ostreich, as opposed to Maharil ("Father of German rite") who proposed to wear upon marriage. Odd, no? There's much to analyze. GC"T to all.

Comment: @Oliver, the Mahari"l never actually held that way. He provided a post-facto justification which was commonly brought in his day to explain the practice, which dated to the increase in poverty following גזירות ק"ט.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt How do you know it dates to the Black Death era? Also, how do you know the Maharil didn't hold that way himself?

Comment: @Oliver, don't have time to find the page for you, but it's in this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoj5lwevr8y9n0d/Tefiloh-Sefas-Yisroel-v.1.16.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Thanks for the cool link. I looked it up (pg. 14 of the book) and there isn't any evidence for both pints you mention. It's pure conjecture.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Why isn't the link you provided from the KAYJ forum constitute an answer?